# Collection of MVC CSS files available?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, asp.net-mvc-2

Just curious - are there various customized `Site.css` files (and accompanying images) that work with the default ASP.NET MVC 2 templates? I'm a stereotypical developer who "doesn't do pretty" so I'd like to find a design that is *good enough* for me to use until I later have a designer come back and *fix* my design.

Are there collections/libraries of various designs out there that work with the default templates? I did find [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/gallery/default.aspx?supportsjs=true) but the 2 popular ones I tried seem like they're for MVC 1, plus they in no way used the default tags with the MVC 2 templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We still have been unable to find a good collection of something like this. While I could be wrong, at this point we're assuming that a good ones does not exist. I hope I'm wrong and this answer is downvoted off the face of the planet and people correct me, but this is the conclusion we came to.

Answer (score 2):

I dont't know about any other designs specifically targeting asp.net mvc, but what I do, is I use any of those free css templates like http://www.free-css.com/ , http://www.freecsstemplates.org/ or http://www.free-css-templates.com/ which do usually have also some layout in the form of index.html, which can be then easily converted into a master page.

Comment: That's useful and all, but requires me to go learn MVC's CSS structuring and apply those CSS files to MVC, or vice versa. I'm trying to avoid this and leave that for a designer to do later - I just want something that will get the system through demos until then, and that's not worth the time investment into doing the CSS manually.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by MVC's CSS structuring. It is as simple, as it can be. Just change index.html to Site.Master (or something .Master) and in the place, where you would like to change stuff (like menus, sidebars, columns or content divs) insert asp:ContentPlaceHolder tag. That's it. Now you have your MVC design. You don't have to learn anything about the CSS.

Comment: I understand CSS. It's not "learning CSS" that's a problem. It's caring about the CSS that's the problem. You're asking me to go through the site and mark up some CSS site-wide and apply a template's CSS to it. I'm saying I don't want to do that. I want to use the MVC template's CSS out-of-the-box with a new Site.css file to make the default a little bit prettier. By "MVC's CSS structuring", I mean I want the Site.css file that you get when you create a new MVC app and all of the classes that get injected from the templates when you add new views & with the default master page, just different.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [ASP.NET MVC Design Gallery](http://www.asp.net/mvc/gallery/default.aspx?supportsjs=true) - I think it's exactly what you're after.

EDIT: Just realised that that is the same site that you've already found. But I think that if there is going to be any common place for default templates - that will be the place where they'll be found.

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: The newest thing there is like a year old. :-/

Comment: Strike that - over a year old.

Comment: -1 simply because this adds nothing useful to the conversation and only provides a link that I provided in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for the same thing, but I think the guy talking about the masterpage has a point.

But now there's also a SUPER cool feature of the Ravor engine that can make it even easier.  This demo they use MVC3

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0O0gi2m_p_o